# What is the default method used by ParametricNDSolve for a boundary value problem?

Tags: differential-equations

What is the default method in `ParametricNDSolve` for a boundary value problem:

```
parsol = ParametricNDSolveValue[ ... ]
```

How do I find if it uses the shooting method or something else?

I tried the following:

```
Trace[parsol[4, 5][0.5]]
```

Giving

[image: the result]

Comment: That would actually be `NDSolve[]` using a BVP method. Have you seen [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html)?

Comment: I have seen that link. I am unable to find which algorithm is used as default in that link.